# case_when - Odd behavior with character data from data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a program to parse and process textual data regarding a financial chart of accounts. I am attempting to implement a naming convention based on a case_when statement pulling values from different data frames. When I do this I get a result of character(0) and cannot figure out why.

I couldn't find any documentation of this specific issue or a general character length limit for case_when. I created a for loop to test character lengths from 1 to 100 in a case_when statement but did not get a similar issue, so it doesn't appear to be that. I've confirmed all my classes match up.

```
# Example data frames
data.functions <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Insurance Services", "Cash"), Value = c("256800", "711000"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
data.objects <- data.frame(
  Name = "Payment to County", Value = "385", stringsAsFactors = F)
data.sources <- data.frame(
  Name = "Supply Resales", Value = "262", stringsAsFactors = F)

# Create value for i
i <- "E256800385"
# i <- "R000000262"
# i <- "B711000000"

# Split up the unique name ID
id_type <- substr(i, 1, 1)
id_func <- substr(i, 2, 7)
id_objsrc <- substr(i, 8, 10)

# Create name possibilities
# I split this out when the issue first occurred, originally this was
# directly in a mutate() statement
# Balance sheet account: Use function only
id_bal <- data.functions$Name[data.functions$Value == id_func]
# Expenditure account: Combine object and function
id_exp <- paste(
  data.objects$Name[data.objects$Value == id_objsrc],
  data.functions$Name[data.functions$Value == id_func],
  sep = " - "
  )
# Revenue account: Use source only
id_rev <- data.sources$Name[data.sources$Value == id_objsrc]

# # Alternative case
# id_bal <- "Bal"
# id_exp <- "Exp"
# id_rev <- "Rev"

# Select name based on ID type
id_name <- case_when(
  id_type == "B" ~ id_bal,
  id_type == "E" ~ id_exp,
  id_type == "R" ~ id_rev
)
```

The expected result is that id_name populates with the value of id_exp:

```
> id_exp
[1] "Payment to County - Insurance Services"
```

What I get is:

```
> id_name
character(0)
```

Same thing for the other two values for i:

```
i <- "R000000262"
...
> id_name
character(0)

i <- "B711000000"
...
> id_name
character(0)
```

However, if I use the alternative case for the name possibilities, the code functions as expected:

```
id_bal <- "Bal"
id_exp <- "Exp"
id_rev <- "Rev"
...
> id_name
[1] "Bal"
```

This is utterly baffling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `case_when` requires that both the LHS and RHS of all the formula, have a length of 1 or n (they must all be equivalent). With your example right now, `id_rev` is causing this unexpected behavior, because it has a length of 0 while the other RHSs have a length of 1.

```
id_rev
character(0)

length(id_rev)
[1] 0
```

This could just be a mistake in the examplecode for `id_rev`, but if you expect empty values like that we can use an alternative variable definition.

To prove the point that `id_rev` is the troublemaker, you can adjust it to even an empty string and it will have an acceptable length, ie 1.

```
id_rev <- ""
length(id_rev)
[1] 1
```

And then the behavior goes back to expected.

```
dplyr::case_when(
  (id_type == "B") ~ id_bal,
  (id_type == "R") ~ id_rev,
  (id_type == "E") ~ id_exp
)
[1] "Payment to County - Insurance Services"
```

Comment: Thank you, that took care of it!